# Create instance of generic class c#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

So here is the code:

```
  public interface IObserver<T> where T : StackEventData<T>
    {
        void HandleEvent(StackEventData<T> eventData);
    }

    public class Observer<T> : IObserver<T> where T : StackEventData<T>, new()
    {
        public StringBuilder Log = new StringBuilder();

        public void HandleEvent(StackEventData<T> eventData)
        {
            Log.Append(eventData);
        }
    }

public class StackOperationsLogger
    {
        private readonly Observer<T> observer = new Observer<T>();
    }
```

I need to initialize Observer observer in StackOperationsLogger without making StackOperationsLogger generic. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What does `Observer<T>` mean to you if StackOperationsLogger isn't generic? How would you use it?

Comment: You just need to replace `T` with the appropriate type, which seems difficult because you need a type that is a StackEventData of the _same_ type... what is StackEventData<T> and why is it generic?

Comment: Make sure you look at `System.IObserver<T>` just for reference because your version is so different. Personally I've been studying the pattern for a couple years now and it is really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One huge problem is the original generic definition of the interface.

```
public interface IObserver<T> where T : StackEventData<T>
```

Since the type constraint is defined recursively you can't use it in the way you want. Essentially type T has to be something like this: `StackEventData<StackEventData<StackEventData<StackEventData<T>>>>` etc. I don't think that is what you are looking for.

I have a feeling that this is what you are looking for.

```
public interface IObserver<T> 
{
    void HandleEvent(StackEventData<T> eventData);
}

public class Observer<T> : IObserver<T>
{
    public StringBuilder Log = new StringBuilder();

    public void HandleEvent(StackEventData<T> eventData)
    {
        Log.Append(eventData);
    }
}

public class StackOperationsLogger
{
    private readonly Observer<DataObject> observer = new Observer<DataObject>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you have some class definitions like the following:

```
public class ConcreteType : StackEventData<ConcreteType>
{
}

public class StackEventData<T>
{
}
```

You could try this:

```
public class StackOperationsLogger
{
    private Observer<ConcreteType> observer = new Observer<ConcreteType>();
}
```

Apparently you have to design your class correspondingly. Above just highlighted how should be the "name" of the classes and what is expected from the `ConcreteType` class you will define -bad name..you have to change also this.

Comment: Except that `Observer<int>` doesn't compile, because `int` cannot be cast to `StackEventData<T>` - whatever that is. So this doesn't seem to answer the question...

Comment: But that doesn't compile either, because `StackEventData<int>`  is not a `StackEventData<StackEventData<int>>`. That seems to be the actual problem in the OP's code.

Comment: @oerkelens Now fixed and tested :) Apparently I had to check it more carefully. Thanks !!